# Relative clause - That + v-ing

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence use relative clause like this:
"She has become the first and only one that working for Pepsi in Laos."
It passed some grammar checking tool like Grammarly smoothly, but one of my friend said it's missing "is" after that: "that's working for..."
Is it correct in grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original sentence is not grammatical. The relevant usage of *that* is to introduce a relative clause but *"working for Pepsi in Laos"* is not a clause, because it contains no verb. The correct version is *She has become the first and only one that is working for Pepsi in Laos."*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that) "We use that to introduce defining relative clauses".

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clause) "a group of words, consisting of a subject and a finite form of a verb".

Merely for interest, note that the same words, but not the same punctuation, may be used grammatically in a statement such as *"She has become the first and only one that, working for Pepsi in Laos, has penetrated the market there."*